# How to move a specific Postgres database to different harddrive?

Tags: postgresql

I have my `postgres` db running on harddrive `d:\`, and also all the tables are placed there by default.

Now I want a specific table to be save to a different drive (say `f:\`). The table is not yet existing.
How would I do this, if possible at all?

Comment: Use a tablespace. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html . Understand, though, that the table(s) in `F:` are **not readable** without the database directory contents in `D:`.